# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'

Tags: python, openai-api

I am getting the following exception when I run the Python code having `import openai`:

```
import openai
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
```

I have manually installed `openai` using `pip3`. Any suggestions as to where I could be wrong?

I have also included my current working directory (where the Python code is) in the environment PATH.

Thanks for your help.

I'm running the Python code in VS Code.

Comment: Are you sure the version of Python you're using to run the code is the same Python that `pip` used to install the module? Are you working in a virtualenv?

Comment: Hi @mattdmo, i am running the code locally in vscode. The python version in vscode is 3.9.7. The python version on command prompt is 3.10.9 Thanks

Comment: Well there's your problem. Modules are only installed for one version. If you install something with 3.10, you can't use it with 3.9, you have to install it again with that version.

Comment: oh..ok got it..will try it out and let you know. Thanks